# following is the javascript code, how should I convert my angularjavascript code in to typescript

Tags: angular6

how should I convert the following javascript code in to typescript?

```js
//getting state and country while changing the city
scope.getStateAndCountry = function(city) {
  scope.formData.zipcode = city;

  //sending request for getting state and country while changing the city
  RequestSender.addressTemplateResource.get({
      city: city
    },
    function(data) {
      scope.formData.state = data.state;
      scope.formData.country = data.country;
    },
    function(errorData) {
      delete scope.formData.state;
      delete scope.formData.country;
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
```